# Is proving "not $A \iff$ not $B$" the same as proving $A \iff B$?

Tags: proof-verification, proof-explanation

Is proving "not $A \iff$ not $B$" the same as proving $A \iff B$?

I'm wondering because I'm looking at a statement in my book of the form $A \iff B$ yet the proof shows not $A \iff$ not $B$ and then says it is complete.

So I think they would be the same but I don't exactly see why.

Anyone explain to me please?

Comment: The two statements are each a pair of implications.  If you take the contrapositive of one pair, you get the other pair.  Hence they are equivalent.

Comment: A truth table is a nice way to see this if you have covered these.

Comment: $A \implies B$ is equivalent to $\bar{B} \implies \bar{A}$ where the bar denotes "not". Try to convince yourself of this with a few examples, and if you are taking some elementary maths courses try to prove it as a good exercise :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of it this way: $A\iff B$ is two statements: $A\implies B$ and $B\implies A$.

Using prime to denote "not", by contraposition we have $B'\implies A'$ and $A'\implies B'$. Thus $A'\iff B'$.

Since this proof goes the other way, we have $(A\iff B)\iff (A'\iff B')$

Comment: Got it thanks pal!

Answer (score 3):

I'll assume you know the [contrapositive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_contrapositive): proving $p\rightarrow q$ is the same as proving $\neg q \rightarrow \neg p$.

With this, it's easy:

$$(p\iff q) \equiv ((p\rightarrow q)\wedge (q\rightarrow p))\equiv ((\neg q\rightarrow \neg p)\wedge (\neg p\rightarrow \neg q))\equiv (\neg q \iff \neg p)$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{array}{c c|c| c} 
A & B & \lnot A\iff\lnot B & A\iff B \\ \hline
\bot & \bot & \top\iff\top & \bot\iff\bot \\
\bot & \top & \top\iff\bot & \bot\iff\top \\
\top & \bot & \bot\iff\top & \top\iff\bot \\
\top & \top & \bot\iff\bot & \top\iff\top \\
\end{array}$$

---

[image: W|A]